# Retrieve WebVie URL Swift || Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UIWebViewDelegate?'

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I would like to load a web page then be able to retrieve the current web page after the user has logged in and been redirected. I have achieved the loading of a webpage but am unable to retrieve the URL after the user has moved to a new page. The current code that I have is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    needlogin()
}

func needlogin(){
    let url =  URL(string:  "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id="+clientid+"&redirect_uri="+redirecturl+"&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+public_content+follower_list+relationships")
    let urlrequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(urlrequest)
   self.webView.delegate = self

}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){

}
```

The problem I have is with `self.webView.delegate = self` . I get the error message :

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type
>   'UIWebViewDelegate?'

Furthermore I have no clue how to retrieve the URL at all and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to conform to UIWebviewDelegate protocol. So you would need to do something like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

}
```

at the top of your class definition.

To retrieve the URL after the webview has finished loading, within your webViewDidFinishLoad method, you would need to do something like webView.request.URL.

**Disclaimer:** You should be using WKWebview rather than UIWebview for iOS + applications. The way to do it would be something like this for your example:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebviewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var wkWebview : WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       needsLogin()

    }

   func needsLogin() {

       wkWebview = WKWebView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
        wkWebview?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(wkWebview!)

        let url =  URL(string:  "https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/? client_id="+clientid+"&redirect_uri="+redirecturl+"&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+public_content+follower_list+relationships")
        let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest.init(url: url!)
        wkWebview?.load(urlRequest)

   }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

  public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   // This is the URL you need.
   let url = webView.url
   }
  }
```